# How to add Custom attribute on minicart?

Tags: checkout, product-attribute, magento2.4, mini-cart, magento2minicart

I need to display custom product attribute in mini cart for each product in the cart. How to get attribute value. please see below screenshot.

https://prnt.sc/-99NK5eeFgAZ

Thanks,
Kiran

Comment: Do you want to display custom product attribute in minicart only? or do you want to display it on both places minicart and cart page?

Comment: Please see below my answer, apply that, and it will be worked like a charm!!!!

Comment: Outcome screenshot: https://tinyurl.com/24r4asun

Comment: minicart only @Dotsquares

Comment: ok @kiran, then it will work with my code which I post below as an Answer...

Comment: Thank you @Dotsquares.

Comment: Below answer working but if we don't have value in attributes then it should be disabled.
https://prnt.sc/_yilr8p5J-L7

Comment: ok, let me edit the code and make it condition...

Comment: I have revised the code so you can update the default.html file with my code.

Comment: Thank you so much @Dotsquares

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> app/code/Dotsquares/CustomAttribute/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Checkout/template/minicart/item/default.html': 'Dotsquares_SellerLocator/template/minicart/item/default.html'
        }
    }
};
```

> app/code/Dotsquares/CustomAttribute/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\DefaultItem">
        <plugin name="AddAttPlug" type="Dotsquares\CustomAttribute\Plugin\DefaultItem" />
    </type>
</config>
```

> app/code/Dotsquares/CustomAttribute/Plugin/DefaultItem.php

```
<?php

namespace Dotsquares\SellerLocator\Plugin;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item;

class DefaultItem
{
    protected $_productloader;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $_productloader
    )
    {
        $this->_productloader = $_productloader;
    }

    public function aroundGetItemData($subject, \Closure $proceed, Item $item)
    {
        $data = $proceed($item);

        /** @var Product $product */
        $product = $this->_productloader->create()->load($item->getProduct()->getId());

        $atts = [
            "custom_value" => $product->getCustomValue()
        ];

        return array_merge($data, $atts);
    }
}
```

> app/code/Dotsquares/CustomAttribute/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/item/default.html

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<li class="item product product-item" data-role="product-item">
    <div class="product">
        <!-- ko if: product_has_url -->
        <a data-bind="attr: {href: product_url, title: product_name}" tabindex="-1" class="product-item-photo">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('itemImage') -->
                <!-- ko template: {name: getTemplate(), data: item.product_image} --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
        </a>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko ifnot: product_has_url -->
        <span class="product-item-photo">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('itemImage') -->
                <!-- ko template: {name: getTemplate(), data: item.product_image} --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
        </span>
        <!-- /ko -->

        <div class="product-item-details">
            <strong class="product-item-name">
                <!-- ko if: product_has_url -->
                <a data-bind="attr: {href: product_url}, html: $parent.getProductNameUnsanitizedHtml(product_name)"></a>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko ifnot: product_has_url -->
                    <span data-bind="html: $parent.getProductNameUnsanitizedHtml(product_name)"></span>
                <!-- /ko -->
            </strong>
            <!-- ko if: item.custom_value -->
        <div data-bind="html: 'Custom Value: ' + item.custom_value"></div>
        <!-- /ko -->

            <!-- ko if: options.length -->
            <div class="product options" data-mage-init='{"collapsible":{"openedState": "active", "saveState": false}}'>
                <span data-role="title" class="toggle"><!-- ko i18n: 'See Details' --><!-- /ko --></span>

                <div data-role="content" class="content">
                    <strong class="subtitle"><!-- ko i18n: 'Options Details' --><!-- /ko --></strong>
                    <dl class="product options list">
                        <!-- ko foreach: { data: options, as: 'option' } -->
                        <dt class="label"><!-- ko text: option.label --><!-- /ko --></dt>
                        <dd class="values">
                            <!-- ko if: Array.isArray(option.value) -->
                                <span data-bind="html: $parents[1].getOptionValueUnsanitizedHtml(option.value.join('<br>'))"></span>
                            <!-- /ko -->
                            <!-- ko if: (!Array.isArray(option.value) && ['file', 'html'].includes(option.option_type)) -->
                                <span data-bind="html: $parents[1].getOptionValueUnsanitizedHtml(option.value)"></span>
                            <!-- /ko -->
                            <!-- ko if: (!Array.isArray(option.value) && !['file', 'html'].includes(option.option_type)) -->
                            <span data-bind="text: option.value"></span>
                            <!-- /ko -->
                        </dd>
                        <!-- /ko -->
                    </dl>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /ko -->

            <div class="product-item-pricing">
                <!-- ko if: canApplyMsrp -->

                <div class="details-map">
                    <span class="label" data-bind="i18n: 'Price'"></span>
                    <span class="value" data-bind="i18n: 'See price before order confirmation.'"></span>
                </div>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko ifnot: canApplyMsrp -->
                <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('priceSidebar') -->
                    <!-- ko template: {name: getTemplate(), data: item.product_price, as: 'price'} --><!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->

                <div class="details-qty qty">
                    <label class="label" data-bind="i18n: 'Qty', attr: {
                           for: 'cart-item-'+item_id+'-qty'}"></label>
                    <input data-bind="attr: {
                           id: 'cart-item-'+item_id+'-qty',
                           'data-cart-item': item_id,
                           'data-item-qty': qty,
                           'data-cart-item-id': product_sku
                           }, value: qty"
                           type="number"
                           size="4"
                           class="item-qty cart-item-qty"/>
                <button data-bind="attr: {
                           id: 'update-cart-item-'+item_id,
                           'data-cart-item': item_id,
                           title: $t('Update')
                           }"
                            class="update-cart-item"
                            style="display: none">
                        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Update'"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="product actions">
                <!-- ko if: is_visible_in_site_visibility -->
                <div class="primary">
                    <a data-bind="attr: {href: configure_url, title: $t('Edit item')}" class="action edit">
                        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Edit'"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <div class="secondary">
                    <a href="#" data-bind="attr: {'data-cart-item': item_id, title: $t('Remove item')}"
                       class="action delete">
                        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Remove'"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="message notice" if="$data.message">
        <div data-bind="text: $data.message"></div>
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: https://prnt.sc/nFbH1d0vql90
how can I disable?

Comment: Did you create an attribute in the product and assign it to them... then put a value in a specific product. Let me know if you have any issues?

Comment: can we display same attributes in checkout summary?

Comment: Yes, we can add as well over the checkout summary. But we need to do some more work on the checkout XML file.

Comment: vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/summary/item/details.html

I override this file in my theme.

app\design\frontend\Vendor\themename\Magento_Checkout\web\template\summary\item\details.html

Comment: Value not showing

Comment: We need to create an XML also and that XML will exist a JS which will call custom checkout template.

Answer (score 0):

How can we add the validations like,

```
if(attribute1 == "Some Text"){
 Then show Attribute2;
```

}

How can we achieve it in Default.html ?
How to add the condition in html for the custom attribute. @Dotsquares